# How to add a global clicked event handler to all buttons in a MAUI application?

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI application that should write the users' events to a log file. What I have been doing is putting this code in each base page or pages that do not inherit from this base page.

I learened that it can be done using button handlers at the depndency injection level. How I can achieve that?

```cs
public class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        this.Appearing += OnAppearing;
    }

    private void OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AttachBehaviors(this);
    }

    private void AttachBehaviors(Element element)
    {
         var tree = this.GetVisualTreeDescendants();

        foreach (Button cbx in tree.Where(el => el.GetType() == typeof(Button)).Cast<Button>())
        {
            cbx.Clicked += GlobalButtonClicked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create a custom button class

Comment: @Jason i want to for all types of buttons. I use a third tool buttons library like Telerik

Comment: ButtonHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (view is Button)
                {
#if WINDOWS
                    handler.PlatformView.Click += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
                    };
#endif
                }
            });

Comment: Why do you want to attach this kind of functionality to buttons? Your business logic or any cross-cutting concerns shouldn't rely on UI controls. Cross-cutting concerns should be designed into the architecture of an application, e.g. by applying aspect-oriented programming. This can be done by applying the decorator pattern or using tooling. In either case, this should be done on a functional level, not in the UI layer. Also, not all button implementations necessarily inherit from the `Button` class. Therefore, there cannot be a *single* global handler for all button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do this would be with a *Style* and command.

In your application-level resource you could do this:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value"{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}"/>
</Style>
```

And in your `BaseViewModel` you need to add this `Command`:

```cs
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand { get; set; }
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClickedCommand = new Command(()=> WhateverActionYouWant());
    }

    private void WhateverActionYouWant()
    {
       //Your logging mechanism or whatever comes here.
    }
}
```

Note that there are cases where if your Button is inside a *ListView* or something you might have to manually reassign this Binding.

Comment: Interesting approach. However, that will take away the chance to bind to other commands. Also note that the `WhateverActionYouWant()` method would need to be `virtual`. In any case, you could probably use a relative binding here using the BaseViewModel as the `AncestorType` to avoid having to reassign the binding.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is there is no other global way other than creating a custom control

Comment: @FreakyAli Thank you for posting your answer but that does not fulfill my needs. I need it be globally

Comment: Are you willing to use a custom control?

Comment: @FreakyAli I already uses custom controls from Telerik & Syncfusion. My request is to implmenet a global handler that adds a custom logging code to each and every button in the maui app

Comment: Yeah i understand but if you want to do this globally that is the only possible way